# Update XML node value with XMLPoke & Nant

Tags: xml, nant, xmlpoke

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Zones>
<database>User Id=myuser;Password=mypass;Data Source=xxxxxxx</database>
</Zones>
```

Is it possible to update the node value using xmlpoke and nant? 
   My New Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  make the entire value a NAnt property

```
<property name="db.string" value="User Id=${myID};Password=${myPW};Data Source=${MyDataSource}" />
```

Then use the `xmlpoke` command, something like:

```
 <xmlpoke file="${YourFilePath}\MyConfig.config" xpath="//Zones/database" value="${db.string}" />
```

Once it locates that node, it will update the value you specified in the property. NOTE: Not tested.